# Exception in using maven-antrun-plugin for Groovy compilation

Tags: maven, groovy, ant, elasticpath

I have a bunch of Groovy files that I need to include into a jar file along with Java classes.  For the beginning I created the separate Maven xml file just for Groovy compiling.  The result is the Zip Exception.

The Maven XML script is as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mycomp.MyGroovy</groupId>
<artifactId>MyGroovy</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>GroovyBuild</name>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all-1.0-jsr</artifactId>
        <version>05</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
   <sourceDirectory>WEB-INF/src/main/groovy</sourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <taskdef name="groovyc"
                                classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc">
                                <classpath refid="maven.compile.classpath"/>
                            </taskdef>
                            <mkdir dir="${basedir}/target/WEB-INF/classes"/>
                            <groovyc destdir="${basedir}/target/WEB-INF/classes"
                                srcdir="${basedir}/WEB-INF/src/main/groovy" listfiles="true">
                                <classpath refid="maven.compile.classpath"/>
                            </groovyc>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Some extractions from the Maven debugging log:

```
[groovyc] Compiling 5 source files to /usr/java/ep622/com.elasticpath.core/target/WEB-INF/classes
[groovyc] /usr/java/ep622/com.elasticpath.core/WEB-INF/src/main/groovy/com/elasticpath/tags/builder/BuilderString.groovy
[groovyc] /usr/java/ep622/com.elasticpath.core/WEB-INF/src/main/groovy/com/elasticpath/tags/builder/LogicalTreeBuilder.groovy
[groovyc] /usr/java/ep622/com.elasticpath.core/WEB-INF/src/main/groovy/com/elasticpath/tags/engine/LogicalOperator.groovy
[groovyc] /usr/java/ep622/com.elasticpath.core/WEB-INF/src/main/groovy/com/elasticpath/tags/engine/MapRunner.groovy
[groovyc] /usr/java/ep622/com.elasticpath.core/WEB-INF/src/main/groovy/com/elasticpath/tags/engine/OperatorDelegate.groovy
Finding class org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit
Loaded from /Users/anarinsky/.m2/repository/groovy/groovy-all-1.0-jsr/05/groovy-all-1.0-jsr-05.jar org/codehaus/groovy/control/CompilationUnit.class

 --------
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run (compile) on project MyGroovy: An Ant BuildException has occured: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file -> [Help 1]
 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run (compile) on project MyGroovy: An Ant BuildException has occured: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file

at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)


Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An Ant BuildException has occured: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file

at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AbstractAntMojo.executeTasks(AbstractAntMojo.java:131)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute(AntRunMojo.java:98)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
... 19 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file

at org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc.compile(Groovyc.java:480)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc.execute(Groovyc.java:376)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AbstractAntMojo.executeTasks(AbstractAntMojo.java:118)
... 22 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.addPathElement(AntClassLoader.java:460)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc.buildClassLoaderFor(Groovyc.java:511)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc.compile(Groovyc.java:469)
... 32 more
```

Comment: Rather difficult to help - requires setting up the whole mess. Any minimal working example? Would be easier to try.

Comment: I will try, is there any example of using Maven for Groovy compilation?

Comment: Don't know if there's really good support. But have read about it, some time ago. Maybe switch to gradle?

Comment: Somehow I made it work

Comment: How? It's really interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the compilation classes in your Groovy JSR jar are really ancient.  I wouldn't advise using that as your dependency from which you define the Groovyc class.  This is quite probably the cause of your issue.  I'm not sure which you were trying to do.  If you wanted to invoke via JSR223, no sense in compiling.  If you're compiling, no sense in using the JSR dependency.

Moving on.  Here's a full example including test classpaths that uses the latest Groovy versions: https://gist.github.com/keeganwitt/d56b4b81165a264061d5.  If you're using Maven, I'd strongly advise you consider GMavenPlus (or Groovy-Eclipse Compiler Plugin for Maven if you prefer).  I've done a comparison to try to help people choose here: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVENPLUS/Choosing+Your+Build+Tool.

Edit: I also updated the outdated wiki page you likely got this from (http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Compiling+With+Maven2).